Return generic to its discrete type
I run a bunch of calculations using Decimal and Double. Without generics there'd be a lot of repetitive code. There are places I eventually need the Decimal in a more native format but I can't seem to figure out how to do that in Swift.
A hypothetical example: there is no log2() in Decimal, but because of acceptable margin of error I want to convert it to Double and use it that way.
Originally I thought I'd just create a generic function that would work for both Double and Decimal
// Dtype is either Decimal or Double
typealias Dtype =  SignedNumeric

func mylog2<T: Dtype>(_ x: T) -> Double
{
    let x_double: Double = Double(truncating: x as NSNumber) //'T' is not convertible to 'NSNumber'
    return log2(x_double)
}

But I get an error, so then I thought I'd just separate them out into discrete functions. After thinking about it I figure T can't expose its actual Type. Then I thought I'd split the function into their discrete Types and try to use it that way:
func mylog2(_ x: Decimal) -> Double
{
    let x_double: Double = Double(truncating: x as NSNumber)
    return log2(x_double)
}

func mylog2(_ x: Double) -> Double
{
    return log2(x)
}

But then I don't know how to get T to use the mylog2() function by discrete types:
func myExample<T: Dtype>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Double
{
    let c: T = (a + b) * (b - a)
    //bunch of other maths funcs
    return mylog2(c) //No exact matches in call to global function 'mylog2'
}

I am pretty sure in other languages there are ways to handle situations like this so there must be a way. I may have approached the problem with an incorrect Swift mindset and there's a completely different way I'm not aware of how to do this. Anyway if someone can help me with the Swift way of tackling this I'd appreciate it.

Do you really mean to return Double from myLog2? This is likely going to cause making calling it a real hassle. I would think you'd want to return Self so that Decimal stays Decimal (even if you do the computation in Double). That said, I would really think hard about supporting both Decimal and binary floating point in the same code. Typically they solve very different kinds of problems, so I'm always suspicious when folks try to merge them too much; what's the ultimate goal? Swift does not support Decimal well (it's a holdover from ObjC, not a core Swift type).

I know it's just an example, but when you find yourself taking the binary log of a Decimal, it feels like you've reached for the wrong tools. There are lots of ways to do what you're describing in Swift, but all require a lot of code. You just move the code around because eventually it has to exist. Most languages that do support something like myExample do so by crashing at runtime if you pass it something unexpected (what if I pass Float and you have no mylog2 for that?) Swift prefers compiler errors to runtime crashes.

In terms of math, most languages include implicit coercion. C automatically expands various types to make the math "work." This can lead to subtle errors, and so Swift intentionally chose not to do this. 1 + 1.0 is not valid in Swift, by design. Other languages like JavaScript choose to just convert everything to Double. This also injects weird bugs for large numbers, and has major performance impacts. Swift chose a way that is more difficult to code, but easier to be correct and performant. It was a trade-off. Swift tends to be pedantic about things; that's good and bad at different times.

Hey @Rob Napier, I appreciate the question! Yes I do mean to go from Log2() -> Double. Reason for that is at that point I'm turning numbers into a visual representation (i.e. color code) and all that finite datais no longer needed. I probably should have lead off with a more solid example of  "func / () -> Self" (divide operator function) that would have returned as you expected keeping data type contiguous. This has to be dealt with similarly as my myLog2() because there is no common protocol that combines divide operator with Decimal and Double.

Just declare your own protocol that requires a log2 method to be implemented. Conform both Double and Decimal to this protocol.
protocol Log2 {
    func log2() -> Double
}

extension Decimal: Log2 {
    func log2() -> Double {
        Darwin.log2(Double(truncating: self as NSNumber))
    }
}

extension Double: Log2 {
    func log2() -> Double {
        Darwin.log2(self)
    }
}

Then you can constrain the generic type parameter to be Log2 & SignedNumeric.
typealias Dtype = SignedNumeric & Log2

func myExample<T: Dtype>(_ a: T, _ b: T) -> Double
{
    let c: T = (a + b) * (b - a)
    //bunch of other maths funcs
    return c.log2()
}

Alternatively, make Dtype its own protocol, replacing Log2.
protocol Dtype: SignedNumeric {
    func log2() -> Double

    // other functions you need on both Double and Decimal goes here...
}


And probably worth making Dtype its own protocol rather than a typealias since I'm sure there will be more than this one.

Thank you so much @Sweeper. I didn't realize you can do such things with protocol. This definitely opens new doors for me. Perfect!

To your "how to think in Swift" question, this is really the heart of Swift. It's all about defining protocols that match the needs of your algorithms, writing general algorithms based on those protocols, and then conforming types to those protocols, often retroactively (i.e. not as part of the definition), to indicate which types can participate. It's a very different approach than in many languages that use inheritance. You don't need to decide up-front what types you can support. You just decide what behaviors you need from the types, and then hook them together. Best of luck w/ it.
